# Drupal 7 front page URL after changing the front page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have used `Configuration|Site Information|Default Front Page` to designate `node/55` as my front page.

How can I create a menu linking to the original front page, i.e. the one with the list of articles?

If I link to `<front>` it goes to `node/55`.

P.S.: I have been able to simulate this by enabling the `frontpage` view, but, if possible, it would be more efficient to just link to the original front page URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know the original homepage is equal to `/node` (for clean URLs) or `?q=node`. Link to either of these and you should be fine.